# Ansible yaml brake long link like string with variable interpolation to multiple line

Tags: ansible, yaml

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
  composer_version: 0.0.7
  composer_download_url: https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/sonatype/nexus/plugins/nexus-repository-composer/{ composer_version }}/nexus-repository-composer-{{ composer_version  }}-bundle.kar
```

How to break this composer_download_url value string to multiple lines, 
to improve readability.

Looking something like this:

```
composer_download_url:
  "https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/sonatype/nexus/plugins/nexus-repository-composer/
  {{ composer_version }}/nexus-repository-composer-{{ composer_version }}-bundle.kar"
```

Tried with indicators
composer_download_url: |
composer_download_url: |-
composer_download_url: |-2
but no luck

Comment: Im facing problem as there will be added white space or "\n" symbol
like: 
...nexus-repository-compose/ 0.0.7/... whitespace after /
..nexus-repository-compose/\n0.0.7/...   "\n" after /

Answer (score 0):

You escape the newline:

```yaml
composer_download_url:
  "https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/sonatype/nexus/plugins/nexus-repository-composer/\
  {{ composer_version }}/nexus-repository-composer-{{ composer_version }}-bundle.kar"
```